# How to display a spectogram inside a UIFigure?

Tags: matlab, visualization, interactive, spectrogram, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to display a spectogram in a UIAxes using app designer in MATLAB 2018. The best method I've seemed to find is a workaround where I display a colored image of the spectogram as below. I've used an empty UIFigures position so that all my graphs have the same position and size as shown in `ax`.

```
ax = uiaxes(app.UIFigure,"Position",app.UIAxes.Position);
[S,F,T] = spectrogram(y,w);
imagesc(ax, F, T, log(abs(S'))); %plot the log spectrum
set(ax,'YDir', 'normal'); % flip the Y Axis so lower frequencies are at the bottom 
colorbar(ax)
```

This however is not ideal and I would like to retain the interactivity of the plot, or at least have a better looking result. Is there a better way to go about this?

This is what it looks like so far - as you can see its not great:
[image]

Comment: What's exactly what you don't like about your solution? You create a `uiaxes` and get the image displayed there. That sounds right

Comment: Its not interactive. Normally a spectagram figure allows the user to zoom in etc, considering all my others graphs are interactive, I would prefer this one to be as well.

Comment: @IntentFilters What if you can't have both a "UIFigure" and "Interactive"? Or if it would be extremely difficult to make the UIFigure interactive?